# Single SASS Function for changing saturation and opacity of a Hex color value

Tags: css, sass

I am using SASS version `1.49.0` on a web project where I can't change the SASS version. I have the hex value `#006ea3` and I would like to grayscale the color and then reduce it to 20% opacity.

Reading: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color

I've added `@use "sass:color";` to my SCSS file and then I tried:

```
background-color: color.adjust(#006ea3, $saturation: -100%, $alpha: 0.2);
```

I'm thinking the SASS version used on this project is too old for the color function and I need to find a way to do it with other legacy methods. Is that right? What SASS documentation should I be looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `color.adjust` function, which you used is **not supported** in SASS version 1.49.0. This version is too old to use this function.

**Solution:** To achieve the same result in SASS 1.49.0, you can use the `lighten` and `fade-out` functions. The lighten function will help you grayscale the color, while the fade-out function will reduce its opacity. For more information on color functions in SASS 1.49.0, you can refer to the [official SASS functions documentation.](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#color_functions)

**Here's an example:**

```css
$color: #006ea3;
$gray-color: lighten($color, 100%);
$opacity: 0.2;
background-color: fade-out($gray-color, $opacity);
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't get it working, but I feel like that's just the build environment I'm working in and this has sent me down the right path and I'll be able to figure it out now. Much appreciated.